# Determine how many times files in a Google GCS bucket were accessed or downloaded

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

Can someone point me to step-by-step instructions for how to track how many times the files in a Google Cloud Storage bucket were accessed or downloaded?  Yes, I know I can create a sink in GCP Logging to export logs to BigQuery.  But it is not clear to me what the inclusion filter should be to only export GCS access logs, nor is it clear to me how I would query the log entries.

It shouldn't be hard to track how many times a GCS file is read or downloaded, but I have not been able to find a step by step tutorial that shows how to do it.

Comment: Your question is too broad. Do not ask for tutorials, that is what Google Search is for. Edit your question with a well-defined problem. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Did you have activated the audit logs on Cloud Storage?

Comment: Have you selected between [Cloud Audit Logs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/audit-logging) and  [Cloud Storage Logs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-logs)? Cloud Audit Logs is separate from Cloud Storage usage logs. Both features provide information about who accesses your Cloud Storage resources, but Cloud Audit Logs is the recommended method for doing so. Also, have you checked this [other post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49001556/17544309)?

Answer (score 2):

With audit logs, you can filter on the objects.get API call
[image]